# What to import for this code to work (and in general)?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import, akka, akka-http

I'm toying with akka-http and while trying to compile the following example:

```
val route: Route =
    path("data" / IntNumber) { id =>
      get {
        complete {
          "GET /data/" + id
        }
      }
    }
```

I find out that I don't know what to include in order to make it compile. Moreover, in general I find myself many times in the situation of *"ugh, what do I need to import for this to work?"* or *"this isn't working because of some import?"* while working with Scala and Akka specifically. I use IntelliJ IDEA but, apart from the fantastic IDE support, it's unable to automatically import the required stuff many times (e.g. when using the ask pattern in Akka). I don't blame the IDE; I understand that sometimes it may be complicated or impossible to import the right things. So, although my question may sound silly, what people do out there to cope with this stuff independently of what IDE is used? and what to add to the code above in order to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the compiler say ? I mean what error do you get when you try to compile this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code should show the structure you need (requiring an implicit `ExecutionContext`) as well as the import to give you the routing DSL:

```
import akka.http.server._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class MyDataService(implicit ec:ExecutionContext) {
  import Directives._

  val route: Route =
    path("data" / IntNumber) { id =>
      get {
        complete {
          "GET /data/" + id
        }
      }
    }  
}
```

As long as you have an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope and you have access to the implicits from the akka.http.server.Directives companion you should be able to use the routing and directives functionality.  This is one way to do that, but you could, for example, mix in the `Directives` trait instead and also get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to find the right imports for implicits in Scala you really need to have good documentation. Sometimes the compiler error message might give you some hints about what imports you need, sometimes not.

Specifically for akka-http, unfortunately the documentation is not yet complete at this point, which makes it somewhat difficult to use.

I looked for the imports for the code snippet you provided and came up with:

```
import akka.http.server.Route
import akka.http.server.Directives._
```

The `Route` import was found by the IDE, but I could only find the import for the routing directives by hunting though the source code for akka-http on GitHub, looking for clues about how the developers intended the library to be used. The required imports should be prominent in the documentation, but it is not there yet. I also have yet to find good sample code for the routing DSL in akka-http.